# How can I give permissions to C:\?

Tags: permissions, powershell

I am trying to execute the following command:

```
Get-vm | export-csv -path C:\vm.csv -force
```

It is returning the following message:

```
Access to the path 'C:\vm.csv' is denied.
```

Is there something wrong or do I need to grant some permissions?

Comment: Are you trying to move a file from a cluster folder?

Comment: I'm trying to export the vm's from the vmm to a csv-file

Comment: Try running PowerShell as Administrator, or PowerCLI as Administrator. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: What happens if you say "-path C:\temp\vm.csv"?

Comment: Don't write directly to C:\ root if not necessary. There. I said it.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend not to write to `C:\` directly

Instead create a folder in the `C:\` directory for example (`C:\outputs`)

If you are still unable to export-csv to the path, you will need to check that you are running PowerShell as an elevated prompt (running as administrator) and that you have permission to the location you are attempting to write to. If you do not simply add yourself to the location with Modify Access